# When using jQuery UI widgets with MVC4, what's the best approach for validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, validation

Previously when writing MVC apps I've avoided using jQuery UI widgets for DatePickers etc as they appear to require manual client side validation whereas the MVC Helpers (I use DevExpress) use DataAnnotations info for Client side validation without requiring extra coding.

Increasingly I'm tempted to add a few jQuery UI widgets amongst the MVC controls to provide a richer client side experience for my clients, but I don't want to have to write additional validation code for the jQuery UI widgets.

Is there a solution or technique available that will allow MVC Helper and jQuery UI widgets to co-exist in a form where the jQuery UI widgets use the DataAnnotations for validation without needing additional client side validation code to be written?

Answer (score 1):

There's no validation in jQuery widgets. They are just unobtrusively enhancing standard HTML controls such as input fields or dropdowns. And because those fields should be bound to server side view models you could perfectly fine have your view models decorated with validation attributes and have all the validation done on the server side. jQuery UI won't be an obstacle at all.